# Merging dataframes with missings in R (within subject design)

Tags: r, select, dataframe, missing-data, na

I do have 10 dataframes for 10 tests in R, that all contain one ID variable as character string and three variables `t1`, `t2` and `t3` all measuring times.

Not all ID are in all dataframes.

I would like create three dataframes out of my 10 dataframes

- the first with t1-variables from all dataframes, the second with t2 variables, the third with t3 variables
- ordered by ID  varaible
- with NA where one dataframe did not contain values for one ID varaible.

As there are missings (not all participants took part in all the tests) therefore I cant use `merge()` or `cbind()`, and my attempts with `sqldf()` went wrong.
I also do not know for which ID variable I do have values in all 10 dataframes.
I am a little puzzled -> thank you for ideas!!

Comment: You can use the `merge`-function, but you have to set the `all` argument to `TRUE`. For an example see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506828

Answer (score 0):

I'll use this reproducible example:

```
set.seed(42)
d <- replicate(n=10, list(data.frame(ID=rbinom(5,20,0.5), t1=runif(5), t2=runif(5), t3=runif(5))))
```

Note it's a list of dataframes. If your tables are separated, you can reproduce this using something like `d <- list(dataframe1, dataframe2, ...)`.

First we rename the variables `t1`, `t2` to `t1.i`, `t2.i`, where `i` is the index of the dataframe, to avoid confusion:

```
for(i in seq(d)) names(d[[i]])[-1] <- paste(names(d[[i]])[-1], i, sep=".")
```

Now we merge all this:

```
big <- Reduce(function(x,y)merge(x,y,all=TRUE), d)
```

It's one big table with 31 columns (`ID` plus 3 `t` per dataframe), filled with `NA` for values not present, sorted by `ID` (default for `merge`).

Now you can subset this to get what you want:

```
t1 <- big[,c(1,grep("1", names(big)))]
t2 <- big[,c(1,grep("2", names(big)))]
t3 <- big[,c(1,grep("3", names(big)))]
```